# Twitter & Facebook API for < iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, deployment, twitter

I've been wondering whether its possible to release an app with the new Twitter and Facebook frameworks that come built in with the new iOS versions but still be able to deploy to older iOS versions, would there be a way to disable the framework if the iOS version wasn't correct?

Comment: It is recommended that you set the Twitter to Optional if your project compiles for iOS versions earlier than 5.0. and Facebook framework to optional if your project compiles for iOS versions earlier than 6.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS 6 you can integrate both pretty easily like this.
Example

```
- (IBAction)Facebook:(id)sender
{

    if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

        SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

        SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
            if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {

                NSLog(@"Cancelled");

            } else

            {
                NSLog(@"Done");
            }

            [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
        };
        controller.completionHandler =myBlock;

        [controller setInitialText:@""];

        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can release an app using Twitter and Facebook but you need to always check the iOS version of the device your app is running on before calling the APIs.
Your app will be without these features in older iOS versions.

It's not such a bad idea to cover iOS 5.0 and higher as in June 2012 Apple stated that more than 80% of the devices had iOS 5.
You can see it at min 69' in this [keynote](http://www.apple.com/apple-events/june-2012/).

For the list of devices and supported iOS version, you can read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices#Models).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use the [Facebook SDK for iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/ios) which provides a level of abstraction over the OS support.

If configured correctly (for example, marking new frameworks as optional as per [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorial/iossdk/upgrading-from-3.0-to-3.1/)) this will run on older versions of the OS and will fallback to alternative FB authentication methods, such as via the FB app or a webview, when required.